# What will happen to a ice cube in space vacuum if you wrap it in aluminium?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water, thermal-radiation, ice

What will happen to a ice cube in space vacuum if you wrap it in aluminium and make it orbit the sun like Earth?

Comment: Is the ice cube wrapped in aluminum foil or is it inside a closed thin walled aluminum container?

Comment: What effect are you specifically wondering about here? (e.g. whether the cube melts/sublimates, effect of solar wind on the cube, etc.)

Comment: What will happen to the ice. If you like send it from Earth and to Mars.

Comment: @DavidWhite Both! Didn't think of container, but that would be nice to know too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of things happen.

First, what happens to the ice alone. The sides that are not exposed to the sun emit photons in a range of the ice's temperature. The exposure from the surrounding space is very low, so this can be neglected.

What happens to the side that is exposed to the sun? Many photons in the range from IR to visible light to X-rays transfer a lot of energy to the cube and heat it up. The heat is dissipated inside the cube and its temperature rises. The cube evaporates.

Wrapped in aluminium, the ice receives less solar radiation due to the reflective surface of the aluminium foil. If you turn the cube, the temperature is slightly equalized from the sunny side and the other sides.

It is much better to shield the ice with reflective surfaces that are at a distance from the cube. More shielding foils, each insulated from the others, are the best way to prevent the ice from melting too quickly.

Comment: Thank you for a very nice answer!